# Titanium mobile, best way to get array value with custom loop

Tags: javascript, android, ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am trying to figure out the best way to gey array value inside the the custom loop. Here is my code, I am not sure if that is a valid way of doing this or there is another way of doit it:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor: '#fff', layout:'vertical' });

    var data = [
    {title:'Row 1',customValue:'123'},  
    {title:'Row 2',customValue:'345'},  
    {title:'Row 3',customValue:'234'},
    ];

    for(var i = 0, l = data.length; l--; i++) {

    thisObject = data[i];   

    var container = Titanium.UI.createView({
        left: 10,
        right: 10,  
        customValue:thisObject.customValue
    });

    var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : thisObject.title,        
        width : 'auto',
        height : 25     
    });

    container.add(label);
    win.add(container);
    container.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {        
        alert(this.customValue);            
    });
    }

    win.open();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is acceptable and is similar in concept to my approach. However, I would suggest you consistently use a unique property name for this custom data where necessary, and allow it to store many properties and their values by using an object. If in the future Appcelerator decides to create a property named `customValue` you may be contenting with the Titanium API and experience undesirable results.

**Passing / storing your custom data:**

```
var container = Titanium.UI.createView({
     left: 10,
     right: 10,
     myUniqueCustomDataObject: { customValue: thisObject.customValue }
});
```

**Accessing your custom data object property like so:**

```
container.addEventListener('touchend', function(e) {
     alert(this.myUniqueCustomDataObject.customValue);
});
```